# Changing "Confirm before tagging" setting in Acrobat Reader via Registry

Tags: pdf, registry, ui-automation, acrobat, winium

Summary : need to change "Confirm before tagging document" setting via Registry keys.

I am working on a deployable Bot that will automate some tasks in a PDF using Winium. In order to have access to the UI elements within a PDF, I first need to uncheck the "Confirm before tagging document" option found in Preference > Reading > Screen Reader Options > "Confirm...".

In order to make this Bot deployable to all machines, I would need to be able to change this setting programmatically, ideally through the windows registry. But I can't seem to find that setting anywhere.

I looked in the Adobe registry reference... but found nothing
(https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/PrefRef/Windows/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it :
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\software\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\2017\Accessibility\bCheckReadMode

For some weird reason the UI tree within the doc is still inaccessible when opening the doc until I open and close the preference though...